# Почтовый сервер на java/php

Tags: email, php, java

Есть задача написать самый примитивный почтовый сервер, цель которого отправлять почту.
Реализация php или java.
Куда копать с чего начать?

Comment: Копать в сторону гугла, если очень примитивно - это не больше 100 строк кода на любом языке.

Comment: @Gorets

> Ответы по типу "кури поиск" обычно не приветствуются

Судя по тому, что автор не упомянул SMTP, стоило бы хотя бы обозначить основные протоколы и необходимый минимум для коммуникации сервера с другими серверами, а не отсылать в гугл.

Comment: это же не ответ был... а комментарий, если в вопросе есть фраза типа "Реализация php или java"... я думаю тут упоминать, что-то кроме гугла будет лишним

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [ссылку](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=simple+mail+server&sbo=kw&x=0&y=0) на codeproject. Уже со строкой поиска. Там, правда, на шарпе, но общих принципов будет достаточно. SMTP и POP3 есть примеры.